# NginX Reverse Proxy Server to backend webservers does not show Websites correctly

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I didnt see any post on how to fix this specifically, so i tried asking myself.

Im running every webserver on a seperate VM, the proxy is on its own VM too. 
everything is running Ubuntu 17.04

So lets get things Straight first:

I setup an NginX proxy server to serve domain1.com and domain2.com.
Everythings works except that some content is not beeing loaded/shown to the client when connecting via the domain. It doesnt seem to load some images and/or css files. I think the only thing it loads is actually html files, but im not entirely sure. Over internal IP everything works Just fine. Btw, im using only http for now.

My default config for NginX is unchanged, my proxy config is as follows(each server block is exactly like this, with key values changed obviously):

```
    listen 80;
    server_name amco.hopto.org www.amco.hopto.org;
    access_log off;

    location / {
            proxy_pass "http://10.10.10.204";

    proxy_send_timeout   90;
    proxy_read_timeout   90;
    proxy_buffer_size    128k;
    proxy_buffers     4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    proxy_connect_timeout 30s;
    }
```

So how do i fix this? I really want to stick to NginX, as i dont want to switch arround things again and stick to learning this. 
Also, excuse if i dont understand what you are saying if its advnaced stuff, as im pretty new to proxying.

Some examples of the loadingfailures are these:

amco.hopto.org

amco-cloud.hopto.org

Also, the loading times are not optimal yet, but thats another thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add to your location:

> proxy_set_header Host $host;

Also you should check here: https://nginx.ru/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect

Comment: proxy_set_header Host $host; didnt fix it. Also, i couldnt find any other parameter on the site you specifite that would fix it. Atelast i couldnt identify it.

Comment: When you open http://amco.hopto.org browser start download links like this: http://10.10.10.204/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/style.css?ver=4.8. It because you wordpress has site name '10.10.10.204'. You must change it. Go worpdress admin Settings->General->Site Address

Comment: Ill look further into it, maybe it has something to do with wordpress, as i didnt do anything with the site yet in terms of config.

Comment: Ah ok. I guess it tries to download the css from my local ip?

Comment: Exactly. Change "Site Address"

Comment: And keep proxy_set_header Host $host in  your location. It prevents you from making mistakes.

Comment: Ok alright! Everything is working now! Thank you so much.